# install qt 5.5.1 msvc 2012 on windows x86

Tags: c++, qt

Does QT windows (x86) need microsoft visual studio 2012 ? 
I have installed qt-opensource-windows-x86-msvc2012-5.5.1 and when trying to build a project get this error :

```
    15:49:29: Configuration is faulty. Check the Issues view for details.
Error while building/deploying project untitled1 (kit: Desktop Qt 5.5.1 MSVC2012 32bit)
When executing step "Make"
```

Comment: Check your project path, make sure they are valid to Qt.

Comment: Do you have mscv2012 installed?

Comment: yes. you need visual studio to be able to compile code.

Comment: no i have not installed microsoft visual studio 2012 , after installed msvc 2012 , i have to use visual studio or i can use Qt Creator IDE ?

Comment: you can use Qt Creator IDE. you can also use visual studio if you want. but you need to install an addon.